# Mapping PDO columns is not working when i try to match to object

Tags: php, pdo

I am attempting to build an API to return data from mySQL.  This is my first time using PDO.

If I do the below, only the ID gets mapped and nothing else. my first time using this so I'm not sure where to look.  Also, I was never able to get this to run locally so it's running against the Live site so I can't think of a way to debug it.

The query results look like this

> ```
> {
> ID: "18",
> Name: null,
> Country: null
> }
> ```

```
class cemetery{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $fldcemetery;
    public $fldcountry;      

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function readOne(){
        // query to read single record
                $query = "select tblcemetery.id, tblcemetery.tblcountry_ID, tblcemetery.fldcemetery, tblcountry.fldcountry   from tblcemetery
                left join tblcountry on
                tblcemetery.tblcountry_ID = tblcountry.ID   
                WHERE
                id = ?
                ORDER BY
                        fldcemetery
                LIMIT 0,1";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

        // bind id of product to be updated
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        // get retrieved row
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // set values to object properties
        $this->fldcemetery = $row['fldcemetery'];
        $this->fldcountry = $row['fldcountry'];     

    }

}
// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare cemetery object
$cemetery = new cemetery($db);

// set ID property of record to read
$cemetery->id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die();

// read the details of cemetery to be edited
$cemetery->readOne();

// create array
$cemetery_arr = array(
    "ID" =>  $cemetery->id,
    "Name" => $cemetery->fldcemetery,
    "Country" => $cemetery->fldcountry
);

// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($cemetery_arr));
```

Comment: If you run the query separately (swapping out the ? for an ID like 18), do you get rows back?

Comment: Yes, that returns the same data `{
ID: "18",
Name: null,
Country: null
}`

Comment: Just for clarification, I'm talking about running the query in MySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin etc.

Comment: OMG, that was it.. `WHERE  id = ?` should have been `WHERE tblcemetery.id = ?`  - Wow, I never would have thought to check the sql since the id was being returned.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE id = ?
```

should have been

```
WHERE tblcemetery.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key for those values needs to be `$row['tblcemetery.fldcemetery']`

Use as in your sql query to change the keys in the result set.